# Why is my Python MQTT subscriber crashing without error?

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I have a python program which subscribes to an MQTT broker, writing matching messages to a database. The program runs for a while (sometimes a few minutes, sometimes several hours), and then stops / crashes, without erroring. When I debug it in VS Code, nothing shows up as being caught in the debugger.

I'm very new to Python so I'm not sure if there's something obvious that I am missing.

The code looks like this (removed some functions for brevity, they're really just duplicates
of what I have included, modified for different MQTT message types).

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from queue import Queue
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import sci_message_pb2
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict
import ruckus_parser_functions as rks
import datetime as dt


def run_client(q):
    def on_message(client, userdata, message):
        scim = sci_message_pb2.SciMessage().FromString(message.payload)
        q.put(scim)

    broker_address = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    client = mqtt.Client("xxx-client")
    client.connect(broker_address)
    client.subscribe("xxx-topic")
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.loop_start()


def run():
    q = Queue()
    run_client(q)
    t = dt.datetime.now()
    print(t.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "Started...")

    while True:
        try:
            now = dt.datetime.now()
            delta = now-t
            if delta.seconds >= 60:
                print(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "Alive...")
                t = dt.datetime.now()
            msg = q.get()

            # Processing
            msgDict = MessageToDict(msg)
            switchStatus = False

            try:
                switchStatus = msgDict["switchMessage"]["switchStatus"]
            except KeyError:
                pass


            if (switchStatus):
                switchStatus = rks.process_switch_status(msg)

        except Exception as e:
            print("Caught exception:" + str(e))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

ruckus_parser_functions.py

```
import mysql.connector
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict
import datetime

class SwitchStatusObj(object):
    switch_id = ""
    uptime = ""
    cpu_percent = 0
    memory_percent = 0
    poe_percent = 0
    status = ""

def process_switch_status (message):
    #print(message.switchMessage.switchStatus)
    statusData = message.switchMessage.switchStatus
    switchStatusData = SwitchStatusObj()
    switchStatusData.switch_id = statusData.id
    switchStatusData.uptime = statusData.uptime
    switchStatusData.cpu_percent = statusData.cpu
    switchStatusData.memory_percent = statusData.memory
    switchStatusData.poe_percent = int((statusData.poeUtilization / statusData.poeTotal) * 100)
    switchStatusData.status = statusData.status
    
    sql = """
    INSERT INTO vsz_switch_status (switch_id, uptime, cpu_percent, memory_percent, poe_percent, status) 
    VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    uptime = VALUES(uptime), 
    cpu_percent = VALUES(cpu_percent), 
    memory_percent = VALUES(memory_percent),
    poe_percent = VALUES(poe_percent),
    status = VALUES(status)
    ;"""
    vals = (switchStatusData.switch_id, switchStatusData.uptime, switchStatusData.cpu_percent, switchStatusData.memory_percent, switchStatusData.poe_percent, switchStatusData.status)

    insert_to_mysql(sql, vals)

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), " SwitchStatus updated in MySQL:", switchStatusData.switch_id)
    
    return switchStatusData


def insert_to_mysql (sql, vals):
    try:
        db = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="xxxxxxxxxx",
            user="xxx",
            password="xxxxxxx",
            database="xxxx",
        )
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, vals)
        db.commit()
        db.close()
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("MySQL error: {}".format(err))
```

The debugger shows the script is still running, the MQTT broker it connects to suggests it's still running too (it's sending PUBLISH to the client), but it's not logging anything out and it's not updating the database. When I run it as a service using systemd it also shows that it's status is "active" with no error / exit codes.

What am I missing, or where am I mishandling an error such that I'm not seeing the stack trace?

Comment: Without some logging it's difficult to say for sure; but try subscribing in `on_connect` (as shown in [this example](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python#getting-started)). What may be happening is the connection to the broker is dropping, the MQTT lib will automatically reconnect but the subscription is lost (so nothing will be added to your queue). I would recommend adding some logging to help trace the issue (and help reduce your code to a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: Most people do a q.empty() check first before doing a q.get()....I suspect that there might be a memory leak if you are doing gets against an empty queue, given that your program runs for awhile, and then just locks up.